# Индексирование файловой структуры

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Суть в том, что мне нужно в серверной части реализовать такой процесс: программа шелестит по папкам и файлам, попутно индексируя и структурируя все это дело в базе данных. Есть ли для этого процесса какое-нибудь название?
Каким образом можно реализовать это?
Предполагается, что писаться это будет на C#+MSSQL.

Comment: Ну вот, допустим вы все *каким-то образом* проиндексировали. Дальше что? Зачем вам нужен этот индекс на `server-side` и какую *настоящую* задачу вы решаете?

Comment: База эта будет храниться на сервере.А дальше я буду к файлам/папкам предоставлять удаленный доступ в соответствии с заданными правами.

Answer (score 1):

Не до конца задан вопрос. Не очень понятно, что вы потом с этим хотите делать.

Хотя в конечном итоге вам понадобится один из двух вариантов:

- MSSQL Fulltext Search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms142571.aspx
- Lucene.net: http://lucenenet.apache.org/

Как работать с первым - вы найдете по той же ссылке. А для Lucene.net есть очень неплохая [статья тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms).